# getting syntax error name 'parameters' is not defined?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

i have written a python script but when i try to run it in arcmap i get a syntax error:
[image]

I cant understand where the problem is.

This code is not complete yet. I want to achieve two things from the code

1. give two inputs and then calculate Fault_loc. If that answer is equal to objectid of input then take corresponding X and Y values from the table and store it in output's attribute table.
2. second part which i am working on is to create a POINT layer and show that X and Y Pointon the map.

But first i want to fix the syntax error i am geting
Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

import os

class Toolbox(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Pin point1"
        self.alias = "alonglines1"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox

        self.tools = [PinPointFaultLocationpp]

class PinPointFaultLocationpp(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "PinPointFaultLocationpp"
        self.description = "pin points the fault location."
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        in_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input HV Line Feature",
            name="in_HV_Lines",
            datatype="Feature Layer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        in_features.filter.list = ['Polyline']

        out_point = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output Point Feature Class",
            name="Fault location",
            datatype="Feature Class",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Output")

        Fault_distance = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Fault_distance (units are in units of input)",
            name="Fault_distance",
            datatype="Double",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        distance_between_points = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="distance between points (units are in units of input)",
            name="distance_between_points",
            datatype="Double",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        params= [in_features, out_point, Fault_distance, distance_between_points]
        return

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        parameters[1].parameterDependencies = [parameters[0].name]
        parameters[1].schema.clone = True
        parameters[1].schema.geometryTypeRule = "AsSpecified"
        parameters[1].schema.geometryType = "Point"
        parameters[1].schema.fieldsRule = "FirstDependencyFIDs"
        parameters[1].schema.fieldsRule = "None"

        id_field = arcpy.Field()
        id_field.name = "Xpoint_output"
        id_field.type = "Double"

        id_field1= arcpy.Field()
        id_field1.name="Ypoint_output"
        id_field1.type="Double"

        parameters[1].schema.additionalFields = [id_field]
        parameters[1].schema.additionalFields = [id_field1]
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Provide error messages if interval is invalid"""
        """Provide error messages if interval is invalid"""

        err_value = "Distance value cannot be a negative number"


         # percentage
        if parameters[2].value < 0.0:
                parameters[2].setErrorMessage(err_value)

        return


    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
    in_fc = parameters[0].valueAsText
    out_fc = parameters[1].valueAsText
    Fault_distance = parameters[2].value
    distance_between_points  = parameters[3].value
    fault_loc=fault_distance/distance_between_points

    desc = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
        #http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/describing-data.htm

        # Create output feature class
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
            os.path.dirname(out_fc),
            os.path.basename(out_fc),
            geometry_type="POINT",
            spatial_reference=desc.spatialReference)
            #http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

        # Add a field and transfer X value from input to output
        fid_name="Xpoint_output"
        fid_name1="Ypoint_output"

    arcpy.AddField_management(out_fc, fid_name, "LONG")
    arcpy.AddField_management(out_fc,fid_name1,"Long")

    #input file coloumns
    field_name = 'OBJECTID'
    field_name1= 'X'
    field_name2= 'Y'

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
                in_fc) as search_cursor:
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(
                    out_fc) as insert_cursor:
                for row in search_cursor:
                    if row.getValue(field_name)== Fault_loc:
                         x=row.getValue(field_name1)
                         y=row.getValue(field_name2)
                         insert_cursor.insertRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the indention for your `execute` function.

```
 def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        in_fc = parameters[0].valueAsText
        out_fc = parameters[1].valueAsText
        Fault_distance = parameters[2].value
        distance_between_points  = parameters[3].value
        fault_loc=fault_distance/distance_between_points

        desc = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
            #http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/describing-data.htm

            # Create output feature class
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
                os.path.dirname(out_fc),
                os.path.basename(out_fc),
                geometry_type="POINT",
                spatial_reference=desc.spatialReference)
                #http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

            # Add a field and transfer X value from input to output
            fid_name="Xpoint_output"
            fid_name1="Ypoint_output"

        arcpy.AddField_management(out_fc, fid_name, "LONG")
        arcpy.AddField_management(out_fc,fid_name1,"Long")

        #input file coloumns
        field_name = 'OBJECTID'
        field_name1= 'X'
        field_name2= 'Y'

        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
                    in_fc) as search_cursor:
                with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(
                        out_fc) as insert_cursor:
                    for row in search_cursor:
                        if row.getValue(field_name)== Fault_loc:
                             x=row.getValue(field_name1)
                             y=row.getValue(field_name2)
                             insert_cursor.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: Great. Don’t forget to mark the answer as correct then.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to be very careful with indentation; the code you have listed looks fine until the `def execute`.  I hope that is just a paste issue.  If not, make sure to properly indent all the code under that method definition.

My guess as to the issue is for the `def getParameterInfo(self):` you must return the params array:

```
params= [in_features, out_point, Fault_distance, distance_between_points]
return params
```

You have just a `return`.

Comment: Thank u for pointing out the mistake. I fixed that return params but still have the same error